Firebase FCM returning Error 403 when using V1
I'm new to Firebase and I'm trying to send a body using the Firebase FCM. (I'm doing a personal project similar to Whatsapp)
I'm using a Expo React-native project. Currently I'm testing using the Expo App on both physical phones (Galaxy S10e sending to GalaxyS23).
I looked everywhere to find an answer but I'm weeks stuck in this part.
The react-native code:
export const requestFirebase = async (): Promise<any> => {
 const headers: {[key: string]: string} = {};
  headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  const jwttoken = 'token that I got using gcloud auth application-default print-access-token';
  headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + jwttoken;


  const body = JSON.stringify({
    message: {
      token: 'token that I got using Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync() on another device',
      notification: {
        body: "This is an FCM notification message!",
        title: "FCM Message"
      }
    }
  });

  try {
    const init = { headers, method: 'POST', body};
    log.dev('headers', init);
    const response = await fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ProjectCodeFromFirebase/messages:send', init);

    log.dev('response', response);
    return response;
  } 
  catch (error: any){
    log.err(error);
    return undefined;
  }
}

The response:
LOG  [DEV] [response] {
  "type": "default",
  "status": 403,
  "ok": false,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
      "cache-control": "private",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "date": "Fri, 07 Jun 2024 13:54:22 GMT",
      "server": "scaffolding on HTTPServer2",
      "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-xss-protection": "0"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/languagechat-8e41c/messages:send",
  "bodyUsed": false,
  "_bodyInit": {
    "_data": {
      "size": 262,
      "offset": 0,
      "blobId": "71025cce-316a-45c4-a323-be52f4194ab8",
      "__collector": {}
    }
  },
  "_bodyBlob": {
    "_data": {
      "size": 262,
      "offset": 0,
      "blobId": "71025cce-316a-45c4-a323-be52f4194ab8",
      "__collector": {}
    }
  }
}

In the firebase console the value of request do increase every time I try.

My V1 is active:

I also tried using Postman but the response was strange so I gave up.
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>

I expected to receive a 200. Because I have another device trying to receive the message.

i think it can be package related issue , try axios

Unfortunately didn't work. I'm seeing a "SenderId mismatch" message. Same 403 code.
